# Windows desktop bridge package location appearing in error messages

Tags: xml, windows, runtime-error, desktop-bridge

I have converted an application using the Desktop Bridge (project Centennial), and it's displaying some odd behavior when encountering error conditions.

Upon entering the "Not Responding" state, the error message to the user displays the package installation folder instead of the product name for the title of the error dialog.

instead of this

```
AppName
AppName is not responding
If you close the program, you might lose information.
-> Close the program
-> Wait for the program to respond
```

I get this

```
AppName_dk2kj67hvux!AppName 
AppName is not responding
If you close the program, you might lose information.
-> Close the program
-> Wait for the program to respond
```

Where the package is installed to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\AppName_dk2kj67hvux

I assume I am simply missing one of the tags that should go in the AppxManifest.xml, but I have so far been unable to find it in the documentation provided by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not missing a tag in the manifest. This is a bug/limitation in the platform that needs to get fixed in the OS, to retrieve the proper app display name from the manifest (which you have already provided there).

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: I have mixed feelings about this answer.  Sure, it means I didn't make a mistake, so that's good.  On the other hand, it means it's beyond my ability to fix, so my customers remain unhappy.  Thank you for replying though.

Comment: My answer was about the strings in the error dialog (which is what you asked about). The bigger question is why is your app crashing or hanging in the first place? Have you looked at those crash dumps?

Comment: Are you familiar with VST?  It involves using 3rd party dlls to provide additional audio effects.  Sometimes they aren't terribly well written.